# typo3 11 backend page should show all languages content on default language

Tags: layout, header, typo3, backend, typo3-11.x

In version 10 all language content has been shown at the default language screen and on clicking at the show button, the page in the default language is loaded in an addtional tab. This has changed in version 11. In the docHeader an item has been added "all languages". At the all languages screen no show button is present. Are there any suggestions, how the backend page layout of version 10 can be restored to version 11?
Furthermore the search toolbox has been removed from the docHeader of the page layout since 11.2 or 11.3. Actually it's present only in the list module.

I've been searching for settings in page.tsconfig but found nothing at all, that seems to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if I understand you... But in the language-view, you have a "View webpage" above each language...

[image]

(Screenshot was taken from [demo.typo3.org](https://demo.typo3.org) (v12), but UI in v11 is the same)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not recognize. But how can I manage to make this all language view the default one, so that the editor don't need to use the dropdown in the docHeader, when he/she view a page in the backend?